# (SAS) Subtraction Many Columns from One Specific Columns (or Multiple Column Subtraction)

Tags: sas, subtraction

I need your help to solve simple problem.

SAS Dataset looks like
(DATASET A)
Column A Column B Column C ... Column Z SSS

I want to make new SAS Dataset looks like
(DATASET NEW)
Column A - SSS  Column B - SSS Column C - SSS ... Column Z - SSS

That is, I want to subtract many columns from just one column !!!
I don't now how to solve this problem using macro or simple trick(or sql?)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Suggest you add some sample data.  Also, show what code you have tried. Have you tried using arrays?

Comment: No macros or SQL 'trick' are need for this problem. An array is the easiest solution. See examples here: http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/seminars/sas-arrays/#same

Comment: As stated your question does not meet SO rules so it's unlikely you'll get answers until it does. You need to add sample data and output, plus shown what you've tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

As the comments to your post suggest, your question is a little hard to comprehend, and an array will most likely be the best bet.

That said, maybe you can use the code below to address your problem:

```
/*Reproducible random dataset*/
data have;
    do i=1 to 10;
        Column_A = ceil(ranuni(_N_   )*1000);
        Column_B = ceil(ranuni(_N_+10)*1000);
        Column_C = ceil(ranuni(_N_+20)*1000);
        Column_D = ceil(ranuni(_N_+30)*1000);
        Column_E = ceil(ranuni(_N_+40)*1000);
        SSS      = ceil(ranuni(_N_+50)*100 );
        output;
    end;
    drop i;
run;

/*Desired result?*/
data want;
    set have;
    array Columns Column_:;  /* The ':' is a suffix wildcard matching like typed variables with names starting with "Column_" */
    do over Columns;
        Columns = Columns - SSS;
    end;
    drop SSS;
run;
```